# How to get fields in table1 with shared field in table2 and add them to existing field?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

There are two distinct tables that share a field called 'path'.
The first table includes a field for the URL path and another field called 'linkTo', which lists URLs linked to the path field.

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| path         | "linkTo"                                            |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| puntonet     | "[{url1.htm},{url2.htm},{url3.htm},{puntonet-2.0}]" |
| puntonet-2.0 | "[{url4.htm},{url5.htm}]"                           |
| puntonet-4   | "[{url6.htm},{url7.htm}]"                           |
| puntonet-5   | "[{url.htm},{url8.htm}]"                           |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

On the other hand, the second table, which is called 'table2', has a field for each URL and a second field called 'KW' that contains the search phrases of users.

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| path         | "arrKWs"        |
+--------------+-----------------+
| puntonet     | "['kw1','kw2']" |
| puntonet-2.0 | "['kw2','kw3']" |
| puntonet-4   | "['kw2','kw4']" |
| puntonet-5   | "['kw5','kw4']" |
| url1.htm     | "['kw1','kw4']" |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

My objective is to retrieve URLs from table2 for each 'path' listed in the first table that share keywords ('KW') with the initial URL and are not already included in the 'linkTo' field.

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| path         | "linkTo"                                                                    |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| puntonet     | "[{url1.htm},{url2.htm},{url3.htm},{puntonet-2.0},{puntonet-4}]"            |
| puntonet-2.0 | "[{url4.htm},{url5.htm},{puntonet},{puntonet-4}]"                |
| puntonet-4   | "[{url6.htm},{url7.htm},{puntonet},{puntonet-2.0},{puntonet-5}{url1.htm},]" |
| puntonet-5   | "[{url8.htm},{puntonet-4}{url1.htm}]"                |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For instance, suppose there is a URL 'puntonet' in table2 with a keyword 'kw2'. In that case, I aim to retrieve those URLs that also contain 'kw2' and add them to the 'linkTo' field of table1 if they do not exist yet for that URL in 'path'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
    `path` String,
    `linkTo` Array(String)
)
ENGINE = Memory


CREATE TABLE table_2
(
    `path` String,
    `kws` Array(String)
)
ENGINE = Memory



INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('puntonet', ['url1.htm','url2.htm','url3.htm','puntonet-2.0']), ('puntonet-2.0', ['url4.htm','url5.htm']), ('puntonet-4', ['url6.htm','url7.htm']), ('puntonet-5', ['url.htm','url8.htm'])

INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES('puntonet', ['kw1','kw2']), ('puntonet-2.0', ['kw2','kw3']), ('puntonet-4', ['kw2','kw4']), ('puntonet-5', ['kw5','kw4']), ('url1.htm', ['kw1','kw4'])

SELECT
    path,
    arrayDistinct(arrayConcat(related, linkTo)) AS linkTo
FROM
(
    SELECT
        arrayJoin(paths) AS path,
        arrayFlatten(groupArray(paths)) AS related
    FROM
    (
        SELECT groupArray(path) AS paths
        FROM table_2
        GROUP BY arrayJoin(kws)
    )
    GROUP BY path
) AS related
INNER JOIN table_1 USING (path)


┌─path─────────┬─linkTo─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ puntonet     │ ['puntonet','url1.htm','puntonet-2.0','puntonet-4','url2.htm','url3.htm']              │
│ puntonet-4   │ ['puntonet-4','puntonet-5','url1.htm','puntonet','puntonet-2.0','url6.htm','url7.htm'] │
│ puntonet-2.0 │ ['puntonet-2.0','puntonet','puntonet-4','url4.htm','url5.htm']                         │
│ puntonet-5   │ ['puntonet-4','puntonet-5','url1.htm','url.htm','url8.htm']                            │
└──────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```